# Searching your old tweets in Twitter

Tags: twitter, search

My username is moo9000. But I cannot search my own tweets in twitter.com:

https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/%40moo9000

Also looks like searching other users has problems:

https://twitter.com/#!/search/realtime/from%3Atwitter

Is there a reliable way to search through your old tweets?

Are there some third party tool which would give a reliable search results and e.g. list tweets by hashtag? Google is **not** capable of doing it, as results are pretty low quality.

Comment: Try this: http://blog.tweetsmarter.com/twitter-search/10-ways-and-20-features-for-searching-old-tweets/

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that Twitter only makes a limited number of your old posts available to search.  IIRC, it's the last 3000, but I don't know why I think that. There are some apps, like [ThinkUp](http://thinkupapp.com/) that can be used to capture your posts over time.

Comment: it's 3200, to be specific